# Adding cutom paper size to Windows 10 Print APP

Tags: windows-10, printing, windows-store-app

Anyone knows how to add a custom paper size in Windows 10 **Print APP**?
I know from older windows versions that i have to go to "Devices and Printers" inside control panel, choose the printer and then select "Print server properties" and add a custom paper size but this doesn't work for Windows 10 Print APP.

[image]

Comment: In the Edge Windows 10 App, Print, left side, More Settings and you can bring up the standard System print function and there you should be able to set Size. Try that.

Comment: Thanks for your response John. The problem is that i can't use any other different way to print because i use a Windows 10 APP and when i click on Print, the only option that gives me is through this awful Windows 10 Print APP. Else i could just use the printer software.

Comment: Did you look down at the bottom for "More"?   It was there on my Windows 10 App.

Comment: It has an option for "More settings" at the bottom but it doesn't bring anything related to add custom paper size.

Comment: I perhaps was not clear enough. Below More Settings is a link "Use the System Print dialogue and there as (on my system) Preferences that allowed paper selection.

Comment: No there is not such an option. There is only "More Settings" at the bottom which brings only a few more options like "Paper Type" and "Paper Tray". That's all.

Comment: You are correct. I tried several things and what I thought would work did not. No such option in the Windows 10 App beyond what you already know.

Comment: I appreciate your time to search this John. I believe there is a way to add custom paper size to the Print App as well. It should be a way!

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by installing the drivers for your printer from the manufacture's website. The default "plug and play" driver that comes with Windows 10 does not have all the profiles. Once the full driver is installed, you should have more options in the dropdown.